# Custom fonts not displayed correctly in Blender

Tags: text-object

I tried applying a custom font to a Text object in Blender. For reference it is this one:
http://www.fontspace.com/herofonts/quartzo-demo

I do get a representation of the font but some special cases do not display properly. For example in the above font having an "R" followed by "O" changes the shape of the "R" slightly. These changes do happen in other software but not in blender.

Is there anything I can do directly in blender? (I found a workaround by entering the text in inkscape. But a direct blender solution would be much better.)

Comment: Other than the Inkscape workaround I don't think there is anything you can do in Blender since it doesn't support ligature font features, as far as I know. Unless you write code to implement them.